# How to replace special characters in bash/sed?

Tags: bash, sed, replace, html-escape-characters

I want to replace some special characters like Á, é, ñ, ó, Ó from an HTML file.

I'm trying with see but I don't know why the replacement is not working even I escape the character.

```
$ echo "aeióu" | sed 's/ó/\&oacute;/g'
aeióu
$ echo "aeióu" | sed 's/\ó/\&oacute;/g'
aeióu
```

The expected output is:

```
aei&oacute;u
```

Which is correct way to do it in sed?

Comment: Your command works fine here with GNU sed

Comment: I trying in Ubuntu. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @GerCas, I gave it a try on ubuntu18.04 and it works ok. I am not sure why it doesnt work for you. Maybe give a try with `awk`. `echo "aeióu" | awk '{ gsub(/ó/, "\&oacute;", $0) ; print }'`

Comment: Add output of `locale` and your `sed` version to your question.

Comment: @Mihir thanks so much Mihir, with your suggestion to use awk it works. It is weird.

Comment: @GerCas, glad it works but what Cyrus says makes more sense. It seems to be a locale issue. Here have a read :[Locale Considerations](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Locale-Considerations.html)

Comment: I've seen a program that does this... recode, encode, something like that?

Comment: @Cyrus I'm currently don't have access  to send those commands on Ubuntu machine. But where I'm testing now doesn't have installed locale but sed is GNU version 4.8